# How to change response json property names only for specific action in ASP.NET Core Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using **ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API**. I have the following response model:

```
public class UserModel
{
   public string UserId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

It produces the following json response:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "userName": "SomeName"
}
```

I am interested in is there any way to change the property names of output JSON without creating a new class? Also, I would like to apply this rule only for **specific action** and keep default property names for other actions. In our project, we stick to **System.Text.Json Serializer**. The desired JSON output:

```
{
    "teacherId": 1,
    "teacherName": "SomeName"
}
```

Comment: If the model contains only two properties, you could try anonymous type.

Comment: Create a `TeacherModel` - a teacher is more specific than a user, and so they represent different things.

Comment: Is it good practice to create a separate model for this if you just changing the names of properties?

Comment: If you ask yourself the question, "Should these two things be able to change independently?", and the answer is "yes", then yes, having two separate models is fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to switch to Newtonsoft.JSON and use the default serializer, use `[JsonPropertyName("name")]`. You may find extensive information from Microsoft @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonResult` class from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace on `Action`.

```
return new JsonResult(new
        {
            TeacherId = userModel.UserId,
            TeacherName = userModel.UserName
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class UserModel
{
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Foo")]
   public string UserId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

.net core 3.* doesn't work with Newtonsoft by default.

you should install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

and add it to your project

services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

Comment: The question's title indicates the change is only wanted for a specific action - this would apply to all actions that use `UserModel`.

Comment: For core 3 and net 5 default serializer `[JsonPropertyName("name")]` should be used.